# Is there a way to search text and numbers in a userform vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a user form with Vlookups to tell me alternative pantone colours to use.

This is working as expecting when I enter a numerical value I get alternatives (including text alternatives e.g 303 suggests 301 & black).

However, I get an error when I try to enter a colour in the initial search that includes text (e.g WG6).

If i remove "CLng" then it no longer works for my numerical values.

Anyone know what I have missed please?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me

UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Pantonetb_afterupdate()

With Me

.rp1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Pantonetb), Sheets("live Pantones").Range("A:F"), 5, False)
.rp2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Pantonetb), Sheets("Live Pantones").Range("A:F"), 6, False)

End With
End Sub
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe use of `IsNumeric` would be helpful here, though `IsNumeric` also has some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Some additional info might help. I'm guessing `Pantonetb` is a textbox control? And what are `.rp1` and `.rp2`? What's the nature of the data in the range you're looking up? Is "WG6" a value that should work?

Comment: ` I get an error` - What's the error number and error description?

Comment: [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and [OFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) might be more useful.

Comment: Morning, apologies for the late reply. Pantonetb, .rp1 & .rp2 are all text boxes. "rp1" is the name for the text box that will show "recommended pantone 1" & "rp2" is the name of the textbox for "recommended pantone 2" . Yes "WG6" should return recommended values. The error message is run time error "13" type mismatch.

Comment: `CLNG` is a [type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) function.  It attempts to convert your value into the [Long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/long-data-type) data type.  As WG6 contains text it can't convert it to a numeric value so returns the data type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

Using my comment of using `FIND` and `OFFSET` and this data:
[image]

```
Public Sub Test()

    'Pass the value to search for and column to return.
    Debug.Print MyLookUp(303, 1)    'Returns $B$3_Result
    Debug.Print MyLookUp(303, 3)    'Returns $D$3_Result
    Debug.Print MyLookUp("WG6", 2)  'Returns $C$5_Result
    
End Sub

Public Function MyLookUp(MyLookUpValue As String, ReturnColumn As Long) As String

    Dim MyResult As Range
    With Sheet1.Range("A3:A7")
    
        'Search for the value.
        Set MyResult = .Find(What:=MyLookUpValue, _
                             After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, _
                             LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        'Short version of the Find line:
        'Set MyResult = .Find(MyLookUpValue, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
        
        If Not MyResult Is Nothing Then 'Anything found?
            MyLookUp = MyResult.Offset(, ReturnColumn) 'Offset from the found value by the specified number of columns.
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: sorry, i have been unwell. Thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: No problem.  Hope you're feeling better now.  If the above answer works for you feel free to tick it as accepted.